# Finding the signs from a string Java

Tags: java, string

Is there a function or something, that is made for finding the signs in a String (e.g. `+/-[]{})(`). If there is such a thing, please tell or if not, just to know to start typing code myself.

Comment: what do you mean by "find"? do you mean "finding out if it exists"? or "finding out where in the string it's located"? or maybe "finding out where in the string, in relation to this other character it's located"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you want to know where in the string + or - are.

To do this you need to search through the string checking for the characters you are looking for. The function below will return you 0-based indexes for the locations of the character in the string.

```
public List<Integer> getLocationsOfChar(String input, char c) { 
    List<Integer> locations = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int index = -1;
    int startAt = 0;
    while ((index = input.indexOf(c, startAt)) != -1) {
        locations.add(index);
        startAt = index+1;
    }
    return locations;
}
```

To use this you would call:

```
List<Integer> locs = getLocationsOfChar("abgc+sda-+", '+')
```

In this example the list `locs` would contain `4, 9`.

When no items are present, the list returned would be empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
String line = "+-/[]{}()";
line.indexOf("+"); // if >= 0, character exists, if < 0, character does not exist in string.
```

Comment: no.. just i want to find how many are the signs, and if can where are there.. the position and the actualy signs.. No it isn't for homework.
David, maybe my question wasn't clear sorry for that but.. im searching for the signs place.. and not only one im searching for all of the signs of one string that i didnt know what signs are in it .Hope i cleared my question

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a regular expression.

Check this out too:

[String API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)